# How to change the load sequence for Azure key vault and spring cloud config?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure

I'm using the [Azure key vaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault)  just follow this doc.

and spring cloud config server ,

i put the configurations of key vaults in spring cloud config

but found out when application start, the Azure key vaults is load before spring cloud config

so means i can not get the azure configs in spring cloud.

is there a way to change the load sequence?

make the spring cloud configs load in firstly